# Getting x axis names for a bargraph in R from a column in a csv file

Tags: r, csv, axis-labels

I'm trying to plot a bargraph of a subset of data that has been ordered according to increasing row sums using R.

The names of the rows are in column 2 of the csv file I'm working from and I'm not sure how to get them matched with the proper bar on the bargraph as the current way I'm writing the code (shown below) just orders the names as they appear in the csv file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
y <- rowSums(domaincolumns)

orderingdatasourcesdomain <- y[order(y)]

barplot(orderingdatasourcesdomain, las=2, names.arg = **MyData[,2]**,
  main = "Number of Domains Covered by Each Source", xlab = "Source",
  ylab = "Number of Domains")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include a small test example of your real world data, maybe the first ~10 rows of `domaincolumns` via copy and paste table or `saveRDS()` structure. This data is just so people can run your test case code above, and see exactly the same problem that you are trying to solve

Comment: `names.arg = MyData[order(y),2]`

Comment: Thank you G5W that worked! Nate thank you for the advice- for future reference do you mean to copy and paste the output in the R console (I'm working in R studio) when I run domaincolumns?

Answer (score 0):

Just so that this does not go unanswered

You need to sort the names the same way that you sorted the rowSums.

```
names.arg = MyData[order(y),2]
```